# looking for a tv episode where tiny men go around recreating the world in between seconds

Tags: story-identification, tv

Looking for a TV episode where tiny men go around recreating the world in between seconds, behind the main characters backs/just out of sight. I think it was older. My memories say it was in Black and White. Similar concept to Twilight Zone's "Matter of Minutes," different execution.

Comment: How is the execution different?

Comment: From what I remember- rather than the episode working under the premise of the characters thrown forward in time as in "Matter of Minutes" and confronting the stagers of the moments, it was more that they were noticing things out of place. We (the audience) were getting to see those staging moments where items were forgotten or a piece of the set from the wrong time frame was put in place almost like a trainee crew member not ye competent at his job. occasionally a correction would need to be made behind a leads back or just out of their sight, to get events back on track.

Comment: Not what you are describing but Eerie Indiana "the lost hour" is close to twilight zone Matter of Minutes.   Regarding original question whenever someone says black and white one has to ask if they actually saw it in 1970s on a b&w tv.  Makes the difference between night gallery or tales of tomorrow sometimes.

Comment: Have you rewatched "A Matter of Minutes" recently?  I suspect you saw this episode on a black and white tv and might be filling in the memory gaps.  For example at the 10:30 mark the fellow controlling time discusses misplaced items. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9XFRfeGBVI

Comment: I wish that was the answer. I've never had a B&W TV though, and it does not account for the size disparity of the "stage setters" it is possible I am doing some infilling but I wish I what the composites are...

Answer (score 1):

It might not be a TV episode but a television two episode mini series *The Langoliers (1995) based on a story by stephen King.

An airplane on a flight from LA to Boston enters some kind of portal and ends up in a time between moments of time.  Many of those aboard disappear from the plane when it enters the portal.

They land at a deserted airport and refuel and try to figure out what happened and what to do.  And then they hear noises getting closer and closer and closer.

A writer passenger deduces that the world of the old moment of time is being destroyed to make room to build the world for the new moment of time.

One of the passengers was threatened with boogymen called "The Langoliers" as a child and believes that the Langoliers are coming to get him.

Comment: The langoliers didn't recreate the world, they destroyed the world that had passed. Something else created the world of the new time. The movie was pretty silly, but the langoliers were scary.

Comment: ha! I was thinking the opposite @NomadMaker - the movie was a creepy concept and the langoliers were silly - chompy pacman / pea pods lol